# How to use ESLint TypeScript Airbnb configuration?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslint

I try to install and use [ESLint Airbnb configuration for TypeScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) for several days and I cannot make it work. Can somebody give installation and configuration steps of a working configuration, please?

Below is one of my attempts to lint [this code](https://github.com/iwis/iw-components) base using Airbnb convention.

[Airbnb configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) doesn't support [Typescript ESLint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/) 3.0 yet, so I will install TypeScript ESLint 2.34.
Typescript ESLint 2.34 doesn't support ESLint 7 yet, so I will install ESLint 6.x.
Typescript ESLint 2.34 doesn't support Typescript 3.8 yet, so I will install Typescript 3.7.5.

I install Typescript:

```
npm init -y
npm i -D typescript@3.7.5 --save-exact
```

I install ESLint and TypeScript ESLint:

```
npm i -D eslint@6 @typescript-eslint/parser@2 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2
```

I install Airbnb configuration:

```
npm i -D eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@7 eslint-plugin-import@2
```

I create .eslintrc.js file with the content:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  //required!; use the previously installed parser; it allows ESLint to understand
  //TypeScript syntax; it converts TypeScript into an ESTree-compatible form so it
  //can be used in ESLint
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',               

  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],  //required for "type-aware linting"
  },

  plugins: [
    //load the previously installed plugin; allows me to use the rules within my codebase
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],

  extends: [  // 'eslint-config-' can be ommited ex. in eslint-config-standard      

    //enable all ESLint rules (for example to explore); todo: what with Typescipt?
    //'eslint:all',

    //ESLint's inbuilt "recommended" config - a small, sensible set of rules
    //'eslint:recommended',

    //disables a few of the recommended rules from the 'eslint:recommended' that
    //are already covered by TypeScript's typechecker
    //'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',

    //Typescript ESLint "recommended" config - it's just like eslint:recommended,
    //except it only turns on rules from our TypeScript-specific plugin
    //'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',

    //"type-aware linting" - rules reporting errors based on type information
    //recommended; takes longer if run from CMD for large project
    //see: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/TYPED_LINTING.md
    //'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',

    //if I use it, then comment all above extensions i.e. 'eslint:recommended',
    //'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    //and 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
    'airbnb-typescript',
  ],

  rules: {
    //can be configured later
  }
};
```

I try to lint my code:

```
D:\workspace\iw-components>npx eslint . --ext .ts
```

but I get:

```
Failed to load plugin 'jsx-a11y' declared in '.eslintrc.js
 » eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
 » D:\workspace\iw-components\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb\index.js
 » D:\workspace\iw-components\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb\rules\react-a11y.js':
Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y'

Require stack:
- D:\workspace\iw-components\__placeholder__.js
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what do you mean *"cannot make it work"*, exactly? What's the setup, and what happens when you try to lint?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: done

Comment: Did you try installing the plugin it says it can't find?

Comment: No, because according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y should be needed only if I use React. I don't use React and it seems to me that I could installed something incorrectly earlier. But I will try to install it. Update: I added links to the packages.

Comment: I installed: `npm install -D eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6 eslint-plugin-react@7 eslint-plugin-react-hooks@2` i.e. the packages required if I want to support React and it helped. I don't need React but thanks to this I found the original reason - I copied configuration from the documentation incorrectly.

Answer (score 39):

The cause of the problem was that I incorrectly copied the configuration from the [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript) package documentation.

I changed `extends: ['airbnb-typescript']` to `extends: ['airbnb-typescript/base']` and now ESLint works.

Answer (score -1):

in .eslintrc.yaml, add

```
root: true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).